# How to use SharePoint web service 'getUserProfileByName' corect in SSRS report query builder?

Tags: xml, web-services, sharepoint, reporting-services, rdl

I have several SSRS 2005 reports that i am updating to SSRS 2008 however there is a data set that requires using the SharePoint 2010 web service 'getUserProfileByName' to complete the report. However, the old query that apparently 'worked' in the old 2005 reports is causing issues in the 2008 version reports. When I trying running the reports both locally and on the SharePoint site i am getting the server cannot perform operation, type error 500 or 'unauthorized operation' errors spewed back at me.

This is the query that is being run in the SSRS reports:

```
<Query>

<SoapAction>http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService/GetUserProfileByName</SoapAction>


<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">GetUserProfileByNameResponse{}/GetUserProfileByNameResult{}/PropertyData{Name, Values}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Can anyone identify what is wrong or how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Reporting server issue and once resolve, I believe that the problem cleared itself up. Seeing as how there was an issue getting a response from the server when function calls were made to it, and that when the server was restarted it failed, led me to believe that the issue was server related. However, I do not 100% know as I left for a new position before the issue was settled. From correspondences with former teammates, testing had resumed and everything seemed to be working.